# Syncing Events between 2 JS apps

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket

I have a game app (Electron) and a web app (testing on android chrome). That pass messages via a websocket server. I want to coordinate a countdown between the 2 processes. It doesn't have to be perfect but What I've observed is that if I run in an environment with low latency it's fine. But the more lag their is in the system it seems like the Electron app tries to start far earlier then the web app. I've tested all my math and it should synchronize but it just doesn't.

First the web app iniates the start of the countdown by passing a starting time to the game app

```
const timeToGameStart:number = peerConnection.timeToGameStart(); // time to game start = 3 x (the longest time it toke to pass a previous msg from game app to web app) 
const currUnixTime:number = peerConnection.currUnixTime();
const startGameTime:number = currUnixTime + timeToGameStart;
const startGame:StartGame = <StartGame>{
    msg_data_type:Msg_Data_Type.StartGame,
    game_start_time:startGameTime
}
peerConnection.passMsg(startGame);
setTimeout(timer.start, timeToGameStart);
```

Below is the app portion of the code that responds to the msg passed to the server

```
const gameStartTime:number = (<StartGame> msgData).game_start_time;
const currUnixTime:number = ServerConnection.currUnixTime();

// if we are on time, wait till its right time else if we are late, start at the next inc 3,2,1
const countDownLength:number = 3;
if (currUnixTime <= gameStartTime) {
    setTimeout(()=>startCountDown(countDownLength), currUnixTime - gameStartTime);
} else {
    const timeWeAreLateBy:number = currUnixTime - gameStartTime;
    const timeWeAreLateByInSec:number = Math.ceil(timeWeAreLateBy / 1000);
    const shortCountDownLen:number = Math.max(countDownLength - timeWeAreLateByInSec, 0);
    const timeToNextSec:number = Math.max((1000 * timeWeAreLateByInSec) - timeWeAreLateBy, 0);

    setTimeout(()=>startCountDown(shortCountDownLen), timeToNextSec);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that these two separate processes are on separate OSs. Which both have a different definition of time. i.e. `(new Date()).getTime()` return different numbers. the difference was 2 seconds so the controller thought their was no lag in the connection and was telling the app to start ASAP.

The solution was I had to define a consistent measurement of time. After each app connects to the server they sync their time with the server by making a request for the time the server has.

I didn't need a super precise time sync so I used a simple algorithm that got the job done. The algorithm was trying to calculate the difference in time the process was off from the server. The formula I used was `server_time_diff = server_time - (received_time - RTT/2)`. Now to get unified (or server time) you just need to call `new Date() + server_time_diff`. RTT is the time it took to request the time from the server.

Any improvement ideas to my algorithm is welcome.